# Adding a working select element to an existing table

Tags: javascript, createelement

I have a JavaScript function that adds a new row to a table. It works absolutely fine adding data types such as input (text), textbox, and radio. It also works using

document.createElement('select');

but as soon as I try to add elements, the button that triggers the JS function does nothing, which I assume means there's an error but I don't get any indication of what the problem is. I'm sure I've just missed something simple but it's been holding me back for hours and it's driving me insane!

The main body of the function is fine, because any other data type creates and adds itself to the table cell accordingly. An example of JS that works correctly within the function:

```
// inner left cell - text input
  var cellTwo = row.insertCell(1);
  var el = document.createElement('input');
  el.type = 'text';
  el.name = 'col' + rowNumber;
  el.id = 'col' + rowNumber;
  cellTwo.appendChild(el);
```

The code to try and create a select element with working options: (N.B. this works if I comment out the options part and simply create an empty select element, so the error MUST be somewhere within the foor loop and must just be a result of my misunderstanding how to create options dynamically:

```
// inner right cell - select box
  var cellThree = row.insertCell(2);
  //create select element
  var dropDown = document.createElement('select');
  //give select element id and name
  dropDown.id = 'fieldtypecol' + rowNumber;
  dropDown.name = 'fieldtypecol' + rowNumber;

  //declare array values to put in option elements
  var optionValue[] = new Array('varchar(255)', 'int', 'date', 'float(53)');
  var optionText[] = new Array('String', 'Integer', 'Date', 'Float');

  //declare option element holder
  var option;

  //loop through creating and adding values to options
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
    option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = optionValue[i];
    option.text = optionText[i];
    //append current option before loop restarts
    dropDown.appendChild(option);
    }
  //append select element to new table cell
  cellThree.appendChild(dropDown);
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `optionValue[]` is a syntax error, you do not put `[]` after variable names in the declaration in javascript. Look in your javascript console to see syntax and similar errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears in your codes the lines;

```
var optionValue[] = new Array('varchar(255)', 'int', 'date', 'float(53)');
var optionText[] = new Array('String', 'Integer', 'Date', 'Float');
```

Should be;

```
var optionValue = new Array('varchar(255)', 'int', 'date', 'float(53)');
var optionText = new Array('String', 'Integer', 'Date', 'Float');
```

Types are dynamic in JS, I would have thought these errors would appear in the JS console for you.